# Dynamic Parameter in fat free template roue

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I have the following duplicate code in layout

```
<repeat group="{{ @devices }}" value="{{ @device }}">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="{{ 'net_device', 'id={{ @device.id }}' | alias }}">Click Me</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</repeat>
```

my routing are like below

```
GET @net_device:/net/device/@id=App\Controllers\DeviceController->show
```

there was an error in output

> syntax error, unexpected 'id' (T_STRING), expecting ')' [D:\projects\lite\public\tmp\29ldv0dewydc0.imz2yj19ml3t.php:26]

How to add dynamic values for `@id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `'@id='.@device.id`. You can look at the generated template file `29ldv0dewydc0.imz2yj19ml3t.php` from your error message and see what’s up.